# Why does overridden auto-implemented property in derived class have a different value from virtual base class property in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, overriding

I have a 'base' that has a `virtual int` auto implemented property called 'id'.

```
class bbase
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }

}
```

When I inherit from this class to a 'derived' class, I get:

```
class Derived : bbase
{
    public override int id
    {
        get
        {
            return base.id;
        }
        set
        {
            base.id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

After initializing the base and derived classes and assigning the value to base class property like this:

```
bbase b2 = new bbase();
Derived d2 = new Derived();
b2.id = 6;
```

When I try to output the value from derived class it outputs '0':

```
Console.WriteLine(d2.id);
```

My confusion is when I try the same approach with virtual methods it works fine. The derived class method with `base.method()` works fine. It returns whatever is there in the base method but why not with auto-implemented properties?

```
class bbase 
{
    public virtual void execute() { Console.WriteLine("base.execute2"); }
}

class Derived : bbase
{
     public override void execute()
     {
         base.execute();
     }
}
```

Comment: `b2` is not, in any way, connected to your instance of `d2`. You can cast, `b2 = (bbase)d2;` and see that it works, but you are creating two completely different objects, the values they contain are not tied to each other.

Comment: after b2 = (bbase)d2; both are zero now

Comment: b2 and d2 are not the same instance? Why would you expect setting a value in one to have an effect on the other? Of course both are zero after that cast - you still haven't set d2.id

Comment: Desired effect of overriding virtual member is to replace implementation if there is any. So if you have `List<bbase>` and store there instance of `Derived`, then the latter type implementation will be called upon invoking virtual member. Nor inheritance, nor overriding has anything to do with 2 different instances.

Comment: Methods are behaviors of class and they do not have values. But properties have values. So two different objects of base class and derived class may have same behavior but properties of them may not have same values.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that seems logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing out on some fundamentals here.

Your `bbase` class defines an *instance level* property "id" as virtual.  This means it *can* be overridden:

```
class bbase
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Derived` class overrides the *instance level property* "id":

```
class Derived : bbase
{
    public override int id
    {
        get
        {
            return base.id;
        }
        set
        {
            base.id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

All this means is that any instance of `Derived` handles the "id" property in this *overridden* way.

When you instantiate your objects:

```
bbase b2 = new bbase();
Derived d2 = new Derived();
```

You are making a *instances* of each class.  These instance's properties have their own values.  The inheritance is not relevant because they are *two separate instances*.  Anything you do to `d2` would not be reflected in `b2` because they are different.

Comment: this is what i am trying to learn when both of these classes have different objects and have virtual methods and prop why derive class method was able to ouptut base class method implementation but not property

Comment: @M.Asif a property has a value, a method is an action.  The _value_ of a property changes from instance to instance.

Comment: hm that seems logical that a property carries a value and method is just a behaviour of a class

Answer (score 5):

Both are two separate objects. So what you are seeing is the expected result.

What you are trying to mock is can be done if you re-write your code so that both variables `b2` and `d2` point to the `Derived` class object like following:

```
Derived d2 = new Derived();
bbase b2 = d2;
b2.id = 6;
```

Now if you do :

```
Console.WriteLine(d2.id); // prints 6
```

You will see the same value that was set above.

[See DEMO here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/32PWuG)

Ideally, i think you should not be calling the `base` that way in the property getter and setter like the above case as you are not doing anything special with value of base so, instead of that just use the default `get` and `set` in  derived like:

```
class Derived : bbase
{ 
    public override int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and now if you write the following:

```
Derived d2 = new Derived();
bbase b2 = d2;
b2.id = 6;
Console.WriteLine("d2:"+d2.id);
Console.WriteLine("b2: "+b2.id);
```

It will output:

> d2: 6
>
> b2: 6

See the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXPlQa) to understand it.

Comment: this works, but i still have a little confusion, methods and properties both are implemented apparently in a same way, but properties needed a cast but methods dont yet both the methods and properties come from different objects. why is so?

Comment: @M.Asif when you cast from child class type variable to parent you don't need cast, but you need in other case (parent type variable to child)

Comment: you are using `d2` both times for print in your exemple

Comment: thanks @Antry for correction, updated both code and fiddle demo

Answer (score 2):

`b2` and `d2` are different objects. You can tell because you did `new` once for each.

If you made the properties `static`, you'd see the results you expect.

Comment: but the methods are also originating from different objects but yet they yield same results. why properties are different? or i am not getting it?

Comment: @M.Asif The method exists in the base and derived classes, just like the properties. The difference is you're assigning a value to the property and expecting it to be carried over to the other object. You're not doing that with the method.

Comment: arent we calling the base class method implementation from derived class??
class bbase 
{
public virtual void execute() { Console.WriteLine("base.execute2"); }
}
class Derived : bbase
{public override void execute()
    {
        base.execute();
    }
}

Comment: @M.Asif Yes, and the property is calling the base implementation also. The difference is the value. There is no instance value involved in your method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `b2` and `d2` are different objects.
so if you set `b2.id = 6;` then `d2` remains to 0, as long as you also set `d2.id = 6;`.

In your virtual method example, you are returning (by overriding it) the base method => `base.execute();`, that's why you're getting the base method output even though you instantiate a `d2` class.

Answer (score 0):

If your code looked like this:

```
bbase b2 = new bbase();
bbase d2 = new bbase();
b2.id = 6;
Console.WriteLine(d2.id);
```

Would you expect the result to be anything but 0? It is the same difference.

Overriding, hiding and the other Polymorphy only maters when you **assign a derived class to a reference of the base class**.

```
Derived d2 = new Derived();
d2.id = 6;
bbase b2 = d2;
Console.WriteLine(b2.id);
```

And that kind of assignment happens a lot in any OOP language. It is between 1/2 and 3/4 of the point of using OOP.